# Influence of physical activity besides the workouts?

Tags: strength, muscle, muscle-mass

If you have a workout plan that you stick to and your goal is to build muscles: is it counterproductive to work physically after you have done your workout already? For example, if you just did your workout and then, an hour later, you do the washing up or you work in the garden or something. Is such a “habit“ bad for building muscles or gaining strength?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of fitness and building muscles is to get strong and enhance every aspect of your life. Working out is a part of your day, not the only part of your day. That being said, it's absolutely fine to do other stuffs after your workout, but make sure your body gets enough energy and nutrients to recover and good rest afterwards. So, it's not counterproductive or a bad habit, but just something that's dependent on an individual's capability and necessity.